# Need help in solving volume integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int\int\int_{V}(x-y)dV$$
where $V$ is volume enclosed by :
$$ S=\left\{(x,y,z):(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}+z^{4}=16;z\geq0\right\}$$

What I did:
$\int\int\int_{V}(x-y)dV=\int\int_{A}\left[\int_{0}^{\left(16-(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}\right)^{1/4}}(x-y)dz\right]dA=\int\int_{A}(x-y)\left(16-(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}\right)^{1/4}dA$
where $A=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}\leq4$
I tryed changing to polars next, but didn't helped much...
I don't think it's relevant, but $(x-y)$ is a $div (f)$ that I got earlyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$, the domain $V$ does not change, but the integrand  $x-y$ will become $y-x=-(x-y)$, which imply that the value of the integral must be $0$.

**Remark**: Indeed, a similar trick shows that both $\iiint_V xdV$ and $\iiint_V ydV$ are $0$.

Comment: could you please explain this a bit more @richard

Comment: @Mykolas: If you consider an integral $\iiint_V f(x,y,z)d V$, and you know that $T:V\to V$, $T(x,y,z)=(y,x,z)$ is a bijection. Then you may consider $T$ as a change of variables, which gives you $\iiint_V f(x,y,z)d V=\iiint_V f\circ T(x,y,z)|\det T|d V=\iiint_V f(y,x,z)dV$. Letting $f(x,y,z)=x-y$, you will see the integral must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Cylindrical coordinates:

$$x=r\cos t\;\;,\;\;y=r\sin t\;\;,\;\;z=z\;\;\;,\;\;|J|=r\geq 0\,\,,\,\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi\;\;,\;\;0\leq z\leq 16-r^4$$

so

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^{16-r^4} r^2(\cos t-\sin t)dz\,dr\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos t-\sin t)dt\int_0^2r^2(16-r^2)\,dr=$$

$$=\left.\left(\sin t+\cos t\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2r^2(16-r^2)\,dr=0\cdot\int_0^2r^2(16-r^2)\,dr=0$$

Comment: Could you, please, explain how you got bounds for $z$ and got read of $\sqrt[4]$ @DonAntonio

Comment: never mind. I got it. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(x,y,z)\in V \implies(y,x,z)\in V,$$
hence$$\iiint_V(x-y) =\iiint_V x -\iiint_Vy =\iiint_V x -\iiint_Vx =0.$$